# I need help in computing the frequecines of fourier coeffients using MATLAB after applying the fft2 and fftshift on map data

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need help in implementing a MATLAB code to compute the frequency of the Fourier coefficients for 2D data. I first applied MATLAB's `fft2` on the data followed by the `fftshift`, all I need to do now is compute the `f=sqrt(fx*fx+fy*fy)` such that `fx` is the coefficients along the columns and `fy` is the coefficients along the rows.

Comment: Good that you wrote code. Please add that to the question in a [mcve] so we can see what's going on.

Comment: The only informations you'll have after applying `fft2` and `fftshift` to your signal will be the amplitudes and phases of the DFT Coefficients. Frequencies are uniformly distributed and only depend on the sample rate of your time signal.

Answer (score 0):

```
data=data-mean(data(:))
dft=fft2(data,1024,1024);
dftshift=fftshift(dft);
wn=2*pi/1024
cx=floor(1024/2)+1
for I=1:1024
 for J=1:1024
  freqx=(I-cx)*wn;
  freqy=(J-cy)*wn;
  freq=sqrt(freqx*freqx+freqy*freqy);
  end
end
```